# Rates of solvolysis of p-dimethylamino benzyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

What will be the order of $\mathrm{S_N1}$ solvolysis rates for these?

[image: Compounds]

I'm confused between the second and third options. $\ce{I-}$ is a better leaving group than $\ce{Br-}$, but the carbocation formed in **2** is more stable than **3**. So how are we supposed to decide between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the second compound, steric repulsions (denoted by the curly lines) between the *N*-methyl groups and the methyl groups on the ring occur:

[image: Steric clashes]

This forces the $\ce{-NMe2}$ group to rotate such that the nitrogen lone pair is no longer parallel to the ring's $\pi$ system. As a result, the nitrogen lone pair can no longer contribute to the mesomeric stabilisation of the second carbocation.

The rate of solvolysis therefore increases in the order: $2 < 1 < 3$. The effect described above is called *"steric inhibition of resonance"*.

A similar effect is observed in azo coupling:

[image: Azo coupling]

In the second reaction, the nitrogen lone pair is not delocalised into the ring and the ring is therefore not nucleophilic enough to attack the diazonium ion.