# Which is the strongest base among the given anilines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, amines

I am facing difficulty in the following problem.

[image]

In my view *N*,*N*-dimethylaniline **2** should be the strongest base because it has two methyl groups which increases electron density of N and hence it can donate it easily than in other cases. However I am not sure about it.

Comment: Related: [Rates of solvolysis of p-dimethylamino benzyl halides](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41402)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, option **4** should be the answer. This is because too much crowding near the nitrogen atom will throw it out of the plane, as a result of the which the lone pair of electrons of nitrogen atom get localized and are better available for accepting the protons. Moreover, presence of $\ce{-CH3}$ groups also increase basicity due to +I effect.

Answer (score 2):

In my view your answer is correct. Among all the compound, 3rd one is the least basic, due to the presence of $\ce{-N)2}$ group which withdraws the electron density of nitrogen and decrease donating capacity.

While comparing $1$ and $2$, 2nd compound is more basic due to the presence of 2 $\ce{-CH3}$ groups as they are electron withdrawing group makes the lone pair of $\ce{N}$  more available for donation.

Now while comparing $4$ and $2$, 4th compound is the less basic, even though $\ce{-CH3}$ groups is present the -I effect of $\ce{-NO2}$ group reduce the the electron donating effect of methyl .

Comment: That was what I had thought.but the correct answer is what is posted in the answer above.